# C++, How include .h dynamically

Tags: c++, header

sorry for my bad english.

For example :

```
//
// File : Main.cpp
// 
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  printf(TEST_DEFINE);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Header :

```
//
// File : test_define.h
//
#ifndef TEST_DEFINE_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_DEFINE_H_INCLUDED

#define TEST_DEFINE

#endif
```

I want include that header, by the compiler or other program. I not want include this header in CPP file.

How can i process ? I'm open to all proposal.

This situation is quite tricky, but necesary for my POC program.

Comment: The Microsoft VC compilers have a `/FI` switch that forces the inclusion of a header into each source.

Comment: have you heard about gcc compiler option -Dname=value ?

Comment: For the hell of it, let's ask...why do you need to do this?  What you're asking about is not really worth doing in standard C++, and the problem you're trying to solve is probably better solved some whole other way.  What that way is, depends on the problem of course.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: Thx, i go explore u proposal, By "dynamically" i mean, not declare header in CPP file.

Comment: Accepted answer solved my problem. Use case: I have a static library with one include that depends on the module that calls it (i.e. name of file `SomeGeneratedHeader.h` depends on calling module).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC has an option `-include` *file* which causes the preprocessor to include the header as though the first line of your program said `#include "file"`

See the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-include-966)

e.g. given a fixed version of your main (which should `#include <stdio.h>`):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf(TEST_DEFINE);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and your header:

```
//
// File : test_define.h
//
#ifndef TEST_DEFINE_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_DEFINE_H_INCLUDED

#define TEST_DEFINE "hello\n"

#endif
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
$ g++ -include test_define.h main.cpp -o main
$ ./main
hello
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot include any header dynamically, C++ is a static language.

You need to include the header statically with `#include "test_define.h"`

The only alternative you have is writing a C++ parser yourself (or using an existing one), reading the header file, parsing it and extracting the symbol you want from the symbol tree. But unless you are someone with years of hardcore programming experience and can explain why you need to do this you should never ever do it.

---

Okay, so we're not talking about anything dynamic, we're talking about a plain old `#include` of a header file that contains some definitions.

What you want is the following:

A file `my_header.h` containing:

```
#ifndef TEST_DEFINE_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_DEFINE_H_INCLUDED

enum {foo, bar} my_enum;

#endif
```

And a file `my_program.cc` containing:

```
#include "my_header.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  my_enum my_variable = foo;

  return my_variable == foo ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: It's just a function call for the example, it's just for use my define

Comment: "Write C++ parser yourself" - I think it is better to remove this. Neither practical, nor reasonable. And the OP was not about this.

Comment: @KirillKobelev I'm just stating the facts and plainly stating that one should never ever do that if one cannot explain why it needs to be done that way.

Comment: Not really i have generate header file with enumeration, and i try to include this header by gcc or other process

Comment: then why do you need to include it dynamically? the `#include` I mentioned in my answer is not *dynamic* it is *static*. Generally when people say static they mean something that is determined at compile time, when they say dynamic they mean something that is determined at run time. The file name of the header you mention is fixed at compile time I presume? In that case there is nothing dynamic about your question, and we're simply talking about a plain old static `#include`

Comment: Also, you should not use preprocessor directives to define your enum, you should just define an enum.

Comment: Yes the term dynamic and poorly chosen. i want add #include in pre-compile time by gcc on other process

Comment: #include "my_header.h", i'm not want to add this in my CPP file. I try to include that header file by gcc for exanple not with the #include rules

Comment: @user1758548, that's what `-include` is for