# Any way to include C++ headers in co​de?

Tags: c++, variables, include

Is there any way to include files in code by using a variable as the header's name? Like this:

```
const char *ch = "test.h";
 /* include it now with the var */ #include ch
```

If the answer is no, is there any function or any way to do this?

Comment: No. include happens at compile time.

Comment: not exactly what you are asking but you can use macros like #if #else #endif along with defined constants to achieve a similar behavior

Comment: These might help you [C++, How include .h dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969672/c-how-include-h-dynamically) and [C++ conditional include file runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930360/c-conditional-include-file-runtime)

Comment: [This has the feel of an XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Why do you wish to do this? We may be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: XY problem? Smells like it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor is doing its stuff [before the compiler even starts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases), so at the time `const char *ch = "test.h";` gets compiled there arent any `#include`s in your code anymore.

> If the answer is no, is there any function or any way to do this?

To answer this you would have to explain what you actually want to achieve. It is a classical [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You are asking about what you think is a solution, but we dont know what problem you are trying to solve...

Comment: I'm trying to make a single program where the user types a file name, and the program creates a header by that name (and adds different macros to it depending on the name), and the includes it.

Comment: @XorTroll  when you run the program compilation is long over. You cannot (easily) modify the source of a running program

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.  Although I caution against such practice.

```
#define TEST_H "test.h"
#include TEST_H
```

Comment: A good reason to NOT do this is odds are way too high that test.h is protected by an include guard that looks something like `#ifndef TEST_H`

Comment: @user4581301 • good safety tip.  The code in one's own project is under their own control.  My guard would look like `GUARD_TEST_H` in my headers, assuming I'm not using `#pragma once`.

Comment: I've built up a fear of `#pragma once`. It fails in complicated build environments, and I've encountered a few too many of those. It's the right idea, unfortunately no one's made it work correctly yet.

Comment: [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#The__define_Guard) suggests using `<PROJECT>_<PATH>_<FILE>_H_`. This is safer because it includes the path in it and you can't have two files with the same name at the same location ;)

Answer (score 0):

While the question asked was about headers, the clarification at "XorTroll Dec 12 '17 at 19:20" sounds like modifications that can be done by loading dynamic shared libraries at runtime via dlopen().  You'd either need precompiled libraries covering all the user-controlled content or a very complex environment including either JIT generation and compilation!